# Relating to Solspace Calendar Events

Tags: relations, solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm using Solspace Calendar for events, I also have a standard channel for reviews. What I need is the ability to connect the review with the event.

Solspace offers "Calendar Events" custom type field to do that, however, when I use it and attach an event to it this code:

```
{% set reviews = craft.entries.section('reviews').relatedTo(event) %}
{% if reviews|length %}
   {% for review in reviews %}
      <h5>{{review.title}}</h5>
      <p>{{review.description|nl2br}}</p>
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   <p>There are no reviews yet</p>
{% endif %}
```

isn't working, and I have the same code working for a standard entry. How do I use relatedTo on custom fields?

This works on a different page with entry present

```
{% set reviews = craft.entries.section('reviews').relatedTo(entry) %}
```

This doens't work when event present

```
{% set reviews = craft.entries.section('reviews').relatedTo(event) %}
```

I've made sure that:

- the event is fetched, and I'm successfully accessing it via code above
- there are indeed reviews with this event attached
  [image: reviews in admin]

Answer (score 1):

You can use them the same way like you are used to everywhere else. All relation fields extend the same `BaseRelationField` so their logic is totally equal.

You can either pass an element, an element id or an `ElementQuery`/`ElementCriteriaModel` but not a string to the function. If you want to fetch all related elements of an event you'll need to fetch the event first

Comment: Apologies made a syntax error here on Stack, yes I'm passing the event object to the realtedTo(), the event is there and so are reviews, but they are not fetched

Comment: Is the code now the code you use? Because `search` is totally wrong. If you use Craft 2 you need to execute `find()` if you use Craft 3 `all()`

Comment: In fact, I use exactly the same code on a standard entry, as I have reviews for more than events and it works fine.

Comment: I've been trying with and without find() not working either

Comment: There must be an error in your structure or something because the code is correct. Maybe some events are disabled or don't fulfill status conditions

Comment: No event is there, Im displaying other information successfully, reviews are there as well I've checked multiple times, and they are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with syntax a bit I made it work, looks like it needs an id, but it doesn't work with the event as an object.

So this works:

```
{% set reviews = craft.entries.section('reviews').relatedTo(event.id) %}
```